# Subdomaining in Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a Firebase project with Hosting enabled. My default url (given by Firebase) is
`<PROJECT_NAME>.web.app`. How can I also deploy to `dashboard.<PROJECT_NAME>.web.app`? I want authenticated users to be able to see this special `dashboard.<PROJECT_NAME>.web.app` url.

Whenever I try adding this as a custom domain, Firebase asks me to add some stuff regarding to `web.app`, which I can't.

Note: I am using React for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get any control over the web.app subdomain that's automatically created for your project.  That is entirely managed by Google.  If you want to customize a domain, you will have to register one of your own and manage its DNS for use with Firebase Hosting as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain).